# Find Id by Normalized Email in the table

Tags: postgresql

I have some table and its short representation would be:

```
|   Id   | NormalizedEmail    |
+-----------------------------+
|   9bn   |      1@OHMY.NET   |
+-----------------------------+
|   2cg   |   NO@OVERFLOW.COM |
```

How I output `2cg` (Id) if I know only email `NO@OVERFLOW.COM`

Comment: `SELECT Id FROM your_table WHERE NormalizedEmail = 'NO@OVERFLOW.COM'` ... you should really try to solve this yourself, this isn't the way to learn about SQL.

Comment: `SELECT "Id" FROM your_table WHERE "NormalizedEmail" = 'NO@OVERFLOW.COM';` worked, without quotes for Id it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT "Id" FROM your_table WHERE "NormalizedEmail" = 'NO@OVERFLOW.COM';`

Quotes for Id are important there!